# Sorting a List<T> when FindAll c#

Tags: c#

I am using the `FindAll()` method which returns a correct list

```
List<AudioSource> playing = AudioSourceRegistry.FindAll(src => src.isPlaying == true);
```

but when trying to sort the list using

```
List<AudioSource> playing = AudioSourceRegistry.FindAll(src => src.isPlaying == true)
    .Sort(delegate (AudioSource a1, AudioSource a2)
    {
        return a1.mixerIndex.CompareTo(a2.mixerIndex);
    });
```

or

```
List<AudioSource> playing = AudioSourceRegistry.FindAll(src => src.isPlaying == true)
    .Sort(a1, a2 => a1.mixerIndex.CompareTo(a2.mixerIndex));
```

results in an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

The sort isn't return a list?

How can I sort the result of `FindAll()` ?

Comment: What is the return type of `Sort`?

Comment: Check the doc of the [List.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FindAll` returns a new list, but `Sort` sorts the list in-place (and so returns `void`).

You can do:

```
List<AudioSource> playing = AudioSourceRegistry.FindAll(src => src.isPlaying);
playing.Sort(a1, a2 => a1.mixerIndex.CompareTo(a2.mixerIndex));
```

Alternatively, you can use Linq's `OrderBy` instead of List's `Sort` (which does return a sorted enumerable, rather than sorting it in-place). If you're doing this, it's worth using Linq's `Where` instead of List's `FindAll`, as this avoids creating an unnecessary intermediate list:

```
List<AudioSource> playing = AudioSourceRegistry
    .Where(src => src.isPlaying)
    .OrderBy(src => src.mixerIndex)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The sorting the list works if I use the deelegate method playing.Sort(delegate (AudioSource a1, AudioSource a2)
                    {
                        return a1.mixerIndex.CompareTo(a2.mixerIndex);
                    });

Comment: @garrilla It may work but it mutates the original collection which, according to your question, is not what you expect.

Comment: @vc74 I suspect he was calling `playing.Sort` on the list which was returned from `FindAll` -- i.e. my first solution -- which is fine.